# windows batch file to read all the super hidden file/directory

Tags: command-line, batch-file, window

I wanna create a batch file that could do something to all folder in the current directory. but I found out that using this syntax

```
for /d %%i in (*) do echo %%i
```

it cannot find the hidden file.
so is there any additional syntax need to be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if anything could be done to fix the behaviour of `FOR /D`, but you could use a different approach. You could use the output of `DIR` in a `FOR /F` loop.

Now the `DIR` command accepts arguments, which allows you to achieve the necessary output. In particular, you can instruct `DIR` to only display the names of hidden directories (`/ADH`) and do so without other information, like date&time and summary (`/B`). Run `DIR /?` or `HELP DIR` at the command prompt for more information.

So, your loop might look like this:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%D IN ('DIR /ADH /B') DO ECHO %%D
```

The `delims` option of the `FOR /F` loop instructs the loop to consume entire lines of the `DIR` output, as opposed to reading up to the first space, which is the default behaviour. You can learn more about it calling the help on `FOR` at the command prompt: `FOR /?` or `HELP FOR`.

Comment: what do you mean by "consume entire lines of the DIR output" ?

Comment: @Fugogugo: If you do not specify `"delims="` in the options and there's a name like `Program Files` in the output, the `%%D` variable will be assigned just `Program`, instead of `Program Files`, because by default the line is read up until the first space character. Specifying `"delims="` causes the line to be read entirely. Alternatively the same effect can be achieved with `"tokens=*"` instead of `"delims="`.